# Правильная запись данных в файл

Tags: java

Не понимаю почему не происходит запись в файл, если не был вызван метод close у потока. То есть вот такой код не пишет в файл:

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader file1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
        FileWriter file2 = new FileWriter(args[1]);

        String line;
        while ((line = file1.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] words = line.split(" ");

            for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                if (words[i].toCharArray().length > 6) {
                    file2.write(words[i] + ",");
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Но если добавить туда это, то все работает:

```
file1.close();
file2.close();
```

Я понимаю, что в `close()` вызывается `flush`, но неужели поток не закрывается после завершения программы ? Как это работает ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Каждый вызов метода `write()` класса `FileWriter` приводит к конвертации символов в последовательность байтов. Полученные байты попадают в буффер, размер которого по умолчанию выбирается как можно большим, чтобы обеспечить физическую запись большими блоками данных, уменьшая количество обращений к диску.

До тех пор пока буффер не будет заполнен, или поток не будет закрыт, или не будет явно вызван метод `flush()` запись не будет осуществляться. JVM не гарантирует автоматическое закрытие потоков при завершении приложения. Хорошим вариантом будет использование `try-with-resources`.